# Program prints -ve integers after 2147483647

Tags: c, gcc

I've recently started learning C. I have read that integer range of gcc is -`214783648 to +2147483647`.

Using GCC on CentOS.

I understood that it is 2^32 is splitted into two parts and 0.

- Is this a imposed restriction on the Compiler ? Any Advantages with this ? or my compiler is 32 Bit ? (As far as I know my computer is 64-Bit).
- If one one go above this limit, what should one do ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you need bigger values, use `long` instead of `int`.

Comment: @user long is 32 bit where I am

Comment: Get used to using and knowing the sizes of these:  `std::uint8_t` `std::uint16_t`, `std::uint32_t`, `std::uint64_t` and their signed counterparts: `std::int8_t`, `std::int16_t`, `std::int32_t`, `std::int64_t`.. Finally get used to knowing and using `std::size_t`.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames What you've posted there looks like C++...

Comment: @DennisMeng Sorry. Forgot this is the C-section. Still, these types should exist in C as well. Just remove the `std::` and use `#include <stdint.h>`:  http://ideone.com/j6WwbP

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames May as well add that the `#include <stdint.h>` is important (for OP's benefit; you already know what I'm talking about)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sizing of integers is platform-specific. C standard does not say exactly how many bits an `int` must have, all it says is that an `int` must be at least 16-bit long. This is not a restriction on the compiler - rather, it is one of many compiler's property that define your platform.

The bit-ness of your platform does not have a direct impact on the size of the `int` on your platform. You can often use the same compiler to generate 32-bit and 64-bit code (with gcc, you can use flags -m32 or -m64), but the sizes of built-in types will not necessarily change.

If you need bigger range for your integers, you can use `long long`, which is guaranteed to have at least 64 bits. In addition, gcc supports 128-bit integer type `__int128`. If you need even more range, you can use an arbitrary precision math package.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with binary numbers and how many bits an integer data type has. Typically an integer is composed of 4 bytes = 32 bits and therefore an integer can store 2^32 values [0, 2<sup>32</sup> - 1] or [-214783648, 2147483647] for signed integers.

As far as I know the behavior if one goes out of the range is undefined. This is known as [Integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

And here is a must read:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number